# Find out which program uses the soundcard

Tags: java, c++, soundcard

I want to find out which program currently makes use of the soundcard. What I want to do, is to access the program afterwards and gain information about the song that is currently being played. I know that not every media player supports such an access from the outside, so I've thought about code injection or something similar, but I have no clue if that is possible (in Java).
I would like to write this application in Java, but I'm familiar with C++ as well.

So my two questions are:
1. Is is possible to access the soundcard to receive information about the program that currently uses it?
2. Is it possible to receive information about the title and artist afterwards?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: It would be best to work on every OS, therefore Java.
But primarily Mac and Android.